# Kotlin Save Firestore query result for a variable

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with Firebase.
I also use Firestore on a website and in a Kotlin app.

On the website, I can save the result of the query to a variation in the following way:

```
const addStudentManu = async($this) => {
 const userId = await db.collection('users').where('neptun','==',ASD123).get();
 const getUserId = userId.docs.map(doc=>doc.id);
}
```

How can i do this in kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it goes:

```
db.collection("users")
        .whereEqualTo("neptun", "ASD123")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            val list = mutableListOf<String>()
            for (document in documents) {
                Log.d(TAG, "${document.id}")
                list.add(document.id)
            }
            println(list)
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
```

You can checkout the sample code snippets in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

Answer (score 0):

While @Dharmaraj answer will work perfectly fine, when it comes to Kotlin, the most convenient way for saving the result of a query would be to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html), We can create a suspend function and map all documents to their corresponding IDs, similar with your example. So please try the following lines of code:

```
private suspend fun getIdsFromFirestore(): List<String> {
    val ids = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("neptun", "ASD123").get().await()
    return ids.documents.mapNotNull { doc ->
        doc.id
    }
}
```

As you can see, we have now an extension function called `await()` that will interrupt the Coroutine until the data from the database is available and then return it. That's almost the same thing when using `async` on the web.

Now we can simply call this from another suspend method like in the following lines of code:

```
private suspend fun getIds() {
    try {
        val ids = getIdsFromFirestore()
        // Do what you need to do with the list of IDs
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage()) //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```